# Weblogic error while deploying JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

The jsp page named uploadTextContent.jsp contains the following code,

```
<html:cancel value="Close" accesskey="c" styleClass="Button" onclick="JavaScript:closeWellFormatContent('<%=request.getAttribute("message")%>')" />
```

When tried to be deployed in Weblogic 10, I am getting the following error while activating changes.

*Substituted for the exception weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException which lacks a String contructor, original message - uploadTextContent.jsp:51:137: This attribute is not recognized. ')" /> ^-----^*

Could you please let me know what shall be the rootcause for this error and how this can be rectified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%=request.getAttribute("message")%>` - this scriptlet contains double quotes and it appears inside of attribute's double quotes.

Try to replace scriptlet with EL expression (to avoid double quotes):

```
<html:cancel value="Close" accesskey="c" styleClass="Button" onclick="JavaScript:closeWellFormatContent('${requestScope.message}')" />
```

**EDIT**

It might be that EL evaluation is disabled. In order to enable it you need to set `isELIgnored` of the `page` directive to `false`:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

This setting will enable JSP evaluation for one page. If EL evalution is required in all or most of the pages then it's better to set `el-ignored` configuration option to `false` in `web.xml` like this:

```
<jsp-config>  
  <jsp-property-group>  
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>  
    <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>  
  </jsp-property-group>  
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: '${requestScope.message}' This is actually passing the same as string and calls the javascript function successfully and not getting the "message" attribute from java file.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting the attribute from java file?

Comment: <%=request.getAttribute("message")%> actually gets a string and passes that as an argument to the js function. But when I used '${requestScope.message}' this functionality is missing and the same ${requestScope.message} is passed as string to that function.

Comment: Got it. That means EL evaluation is disabled. What JSP version do you use?

Comment: Oh. I do not have an idea on that! Can you let me know how to find it....? and pls give a solution to proceed.

Comment: Check out points described here - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro13.html#wp83214

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6143/discussion-between-ivan-yatskevich-and-lgap)